# Como retornar 10 em 10 linhas do select ao clicar um botao em php

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho muitos dados em uma base de dados e preciso exibi-los em php. Uma vez que tenho por exemplo 100 linhas, não vou exibi-los todos de uma e única vez porque a página ia ficar desestruturada.

A ideia eh, exibir as últimas 10 linhas em primeiro. Se o usuário clicar em um botão `mais`, exibe as outras 10 e assim sucessivamente ate acabar todas 100, como no *Gmail*.

Como isso se faz?

Comment: Poste o código que você já fez. Sugiro da uma pesquisada sobre paginação.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from clientes where ativo = 'S' limit 0, 10
```

Crie variáveis para ir alterando o valor para mais ou para menos.
Ex.: O botão avançar aumenta 10 e assim por diante...

Comment: desculpa, nao percebi correctamente a sua sugestao, na verdade e que, nao faco ideia de onde vou aplicar essas variaveis. Sera que iram servir no limit???. Do tipo duas variaveis do limit, uma de inicio, outra do fim???. Peco pra esclarecer um pouco com mais detalhes